# @ApplicationPath annotation isn't getting picked up #3140

Tags: java, vert.x, resteasy

I'm trying to put together a vert.x application with resteasy. While the application gets loaded and the server starts up. I expected `/v1/health` to work but it just throws a `404`

**Main.java**

```java
public class Main extends AbstractVerticle {
    private static VertxResteasyDeployment deployment;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        deployment = new VertxResteasyDeployment();
        deployment.setApplicationClass("starter.rx.endpoint.V1");
        deployment.start();
        vertx.deployVerticle("starter.rx.Main");
    }

    @Override
    public Completable rxStart() {
        VertxRequestHandler handler = new VertxRequestHandler(vertx.getDelegate(), deployment);

        return vertx.createHttpServer()
                .requestHandler(x -> handler.handle(x.getDelegate()))
                .rxListen(80)
                .ignoreElement();
    }
}
```

**V1.java**

```java
@ApplicationPath("v1")
public class V1 extends Application {
    private final Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();

    public V1() {
        singletons.add(new Management());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

**Management.java**

```java
@Path("")
public class Management {
    @GET
    @Path("health")
    public CompletionStage<String> health() {
        return Flowable.just("healthy").singleStage("");
    }
}
```

**Logs**

```
22:48:47.658 [main] INFO  o.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n -
                RESTEASY002225: Deploying jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application: class starter.rx.endpoint.V1
22:48:47.662 [main] INFO  o.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n -
                RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource starter.rx.endpoint.Management from Application class starter.rx.endpoint.V1
```

**Output**

```bash
$ curl http://localhost:80/health
healthy

$ curl -i http://localhost:80/v1/health
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

These are the libs that I'm using

```
      "io.vertx" % "vertx-core" % "4.3.1",
      "org.jboss.resteasy" % "resteasy-vertx" % "6.0.1.Final",
      "io.vertx" % "vertx-rx-java3" % "4.3.1",
```

Comment: It probably doesn't read the annotation. Looking at [the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.0.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Embedded_Container.html#d4e1586), there's `setRootResourcePath()` method. That sounds like it would work.

Comment: Just for completeness this was asked here as well https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy/discussions/3140. I don't think there is a way without configuring the path for Vert.x or using the `VertxJaxrsServer` directly.